# Edit Tab Bar Controller for All Items Swift IOs Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to edit all tab bar items With Code .
My Tab bar controller have 8 Items , the system Add an "More"  Button .
I have edit the 4 first Items but now i want to edit the Next of the Tab :

> tabBarController?.tabBar.items![1].title = translate_tab(item: 1, Lang: Lang)
>
> tabBarController?.tabBar.items![0].title = translate_tab(item: 0, Lang: Lang)
>
> tabBarController?.tabBar.items![2].title = translate_tab(item: 2, Lang: Lang)
>
> tabBarController?.tabBar.items![3].title = translate_tab(item: 3, Lang: Lang)
>
> tabBarController?.tabBar.items![4].title = translate_tab(item: 4, Lang: Lang)

The Error for the Tab Number 5 :

> Thread 1: Exception: "*** __boundsFail: index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]"

Thanks For All :)
Zied.

Comment: All your tabs represent a ViewController, so you can do this customization in your ViewControllers. And also this provides you to change tab order without touching your customization code and maybe you can use your ViewController on another tabbar with same customization. However, this may make some problem if you use same ViewController class for multiple tabs.

Comment: Can you give me an exemple please ?
i'm new in swift Code

Comment: For example, Let's say the class of your ViewConttroller of the first tab is ```MyFirtsViewController```. In ```viewDidLoad()``` method of this class, you can write this. 

```tabBarItem.title = "Title of tab"```

You can do this all your ViewController classes.